# How to add a table row to thead section of a gridview?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, row

**CREATE A THEAD SECTION IN YOUR GRIDVIEW**

```
  Protected Overrides Sub OnPreRenderComplete(ByVal e As EventArgs)
    If (gv.Rows.Count > 0) Then
      gv.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader
    End If
  End Sub
```

**INSERT A ROW WITH CONTENT INTO YOUR GRIDVIEW**

```
  Protected Sub gv_OnDataBound(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles gv.DataBound
    Dim row As New GridViewRow(0, 0, DataControlRowType.Header, DataControlRowState.Normal)
    For i As Integer = 0 To gv.Columns.Count - 1
      Dim cell As New TableHeaderCell()
      Dim txtBx As New TextBox()
      cell.Controls.Add(txtBx)
      row.Controls.Add(cell)
    Next
    gv.HeaderRow.Parent.Controls.AddAt(1, row)
  End Sub
End Class
```

This will insert a row with a textbox within each cell `<th>` at row 1.

---

## QUESTION

How to insert a row (as in the above example) into the `thead` section of a gridview?

Doing this on the aspx page or in the VB is fine.

Comment: What's not working?  It...looks like you're creating a thead section, and adding a row.

Comment: The code above creates a th cell in the 'tbody' section not thead. Although I've found a solution now that I will add. Thanks for responding.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.  Huh, I've never tried to do that before.  I'll give some thought to how you could do that in the VB code, to see if anything comes to mind.  Good solution with the markup, though.

Comment: @jadarnel27 That would be great thanks. I basically just want to add an additional row to the thead section. My answer below inserts the data into a single row.

Comment: Just curious, what if you set `row.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader` before you add it to the GridView (in your OnDataBound event), as you did with the HeaderRow in the PreRender event?

Comment: @jadarnel27 As simple as that!. Please post this as an answer so I can mark you as a genius. Thanks Again =)

Comment: Haha, done!  And you're very welcome.  Though I don't think I qualify as a genius, I *am* glad to be able to help =)

Comment: @jadarnel27 Nice tunes by the way and Bring back the hornets!

Comment: Thanks, I'm glad you enjoyed the music =)  Also: [they totally are bringing back the Hornets!!!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charlotte_Bobcats#2012.E2.80.93present:_.27Buzz_City.27_.E2.80.93_The_Hornets_Return)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your OnDataBound event, try setting the row you created to be in the "TableHeader" section (like you did in the PreRenderComplete event) prior to adding it to the GridView:

```
row.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader
```

Since this sets the section of the table where the row belongs (header, footer, body), it should cause your row to wind up in the right place.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find a way to do this in vb.
To apply content to the existing tr th row in the thead section you can use.

```
  <asp:TemplateField>
    <HeaderTemplate>
      <p>COL TITLE</p>
      <asp:TextBox ID="txBx" runat="server"/>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
      CELL DATA
    </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateField>
```

Which will result in:

```
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>
          <p>COL TITLE</p>
          <input id="txBx" type="text"/>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          COL DATA
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
```